# Filter on filetype when getting objects from AWS S3 bucket in Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-connector

I am using Mule 4 and Anypoint Studio 7 and I only want to get the Excel files from my S3 bucket in AWS.  I am looking for a way to filter on the Excel filetype like *.xlsx but not sure where I can do this in the connector.

My code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:s3="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/s3"
    xmlns:sftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp/current/mule-sftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/s3 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/s3/current/mule-s3.xsd">
    <flow name="getExcelFiles" doc:id="21bd363a-166e-4fc2-9246-dd6f48763db7" >
        <flow-ref doc:name="logStartFlow" doc:id="b2504769-bd82-44a2-aab3-d6427c04bbde" name="logStartFlow"/>
        <s3:list-objects doc:name="List objects" doc:id="640ed7a3-2e0f-4c5d-99a1-fd503d02f055" config-ref="Amazon_S3_Configuration" bucketName="myBucket"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="f0989986-2d2e-4cc9-b51e-d61cf9d01210" >
            <s3:get-object doc:name="Get File from AWS S3" doc:id="568ed3c4-d7f8-4657-a515-835e5671b72c" config-ref="Amazon_S3_Configuration" bucketName="#[payload.bucketName]" key="#[payload.key]"/>
        </foreach>
        <flow-ref doc:name="logCompletedFlow" doc:id="e4df0b09-4e4b-4016-bacd-2b34062356a2" name="logCompletedFlow"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The connector only supports full keys. So instead, you can wrap the get-object call in a choice to only process keys that match using `endsWith` for the file extension. You can change this to check regex etc:

```
  <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="f0989986-2d2e-4cc9-b51e-d61cf9d01210" >
       <choice>
          <when expression="#[payload.key endsWith ".xlsx"]">
                <s3:get-object doc:name="Get File from AWS S3" doc:id="568ed3c4-d7f8-4657-a515-835e5671b72c" config-ref="Amazon_S3_Configuration" bucketName="#[payload.bucketName]" key="#[payload.key]"/>
          </when>
       </choice
   </foreach>
```

Also for future, the connector release notes does mention:

> "Triggers - You can now start a flow with the Amazon S3 Connector
>   every time an object of a specific type is created, updated, or
>   deleted."

That might be helpful as well but I can't find any examples atm.